# Can an MS SQL 2005 DB Files be Attach to MS 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

Is it possible to Attach SQL Server 2005 Mdf , Ldf file to MS SQL Server 2008 instance?

I Try to do so .

[image]

And selected respective Files But, I am getting following error Message

[image]

And when Click OK getting following error Message

[image]

Comment: Possibly.  Did you try?

Comment: Yes getting error message

Comment: And what did the hyperlink in the message column say?

Comment: Attach database failed for Server '...-PC\SQLEXPRESS'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)                                            An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there should be no problem with this.

Note however, that once you do this, it will become a 2008 database (even if its compatibility level is still left at 2005), and so you will not ever be able to reconnect it back to a 2005 Sql Server.

---

You've just added the Full-Text Catalog message.  They're more complicated, and you should follow the migration guidelines at Microsoft.  Also, you usually must maintain the same *Edition* level across versions.  So going from 2005 Enterprise Edition to 2008 Standard Edition, is not directly possible.